# I need add button link to a new page in Success.phtml (checkout process), how do I?

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout

I need to add a button in `success.phtml` page of checkout process. This button should redirect to a new page. How Can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

try this

create a custom module and below files in the module.

> **File**:-Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_onepage_success.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <container name="successinfo" before="checkout.success">
                <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Onepage\Success" name="success.grandtotal" template="Vendor_Module::success_message_button.phtml"/>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Create a block for the business logic of the template.

> **File**:- Vendor/Ordersuccess/Block/Onepage/Success.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Onepage;

use Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success as MagentoSuccess;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Config;
use Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context as AppContext;

class Success extends MagentoSuccess
{

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Config $orderConfig,
        AppContext $httpContext,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $httpContext, $data);
    }

    public function getCustomURl()
    {
        //Write your code here
    }
}
```

Create Button in Template file

> **File**:- Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/success_message_button.phtml

```
<?php $URl = $block->getCustomURl(); ?>

<a class="newbtn" href="<?= $URl ?>">My button</a>


<style type="text/css">
.newbtn{
       display:block;
       width:115px;
       height:25px;
       background:black;
       padding:10px;
       text-align:center;
       border-radius:5px;
       color:white;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

Open Your success.phtml Page in Notepad++ or some editor

**Add a Anchor Tag**

**HTML**

```
<a class="sample" href="http://[Your URL to Redirect]">My button</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.sample{
       display:block;
       width:115px;
       height:25px;
       background:black;
       padding:10px;
       text-align:center;
       border-radius:5px;
       color:white;
}
```

follow this in your success.phtml page it will works

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I want to link a new page to that href. How do I add  new page (preferred to be in "app\design\frontend\[theme]\default\template\checkout" folder?

Comment: create a new page in cms or in checkout folder. if u think my answer is helpful give a vote up.:-)

Comment: created new page in checkout folder and linked it, did not worked. Getting 404 error.

Comment: create a cms page and give link

Comment: created cms page and linked but form submit is not working on that page. :(

Comment: Give same id,class,function of other submit button of magento

Comment: Give reputation brother